# Error 1054 after start fetching on MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

My query had 3 `UNION` working, and I need to add a fourth one.

The query is:

```
SELECT SQL_CACHE posts.*
                FROM (

                    SELECT posts.id, posts.text, posts.image, posts.date, posts.status, posts.location as postLocation, posts.user AS user, users.name, users.username, users.photo, users.location,users.bio, users.background, groups_posts.group as groupId, null as groupName, sum(r.rating) as rating
                    ,(
                        select count(re.id ) 
                        FROM relations re
                        WHERE re.user = users.id
                    ) as numfollowing,
                    (
                        select count(re.id ) 
                        FROM relations re
                        WHERE re.friend = users.id
                    ) as numfollowers,
                    (
                        select count(re.id)
                        FROM relations re
                        where re.friend = users.id
                        AND re.user = 24527
                    ) as following,
                    (
                        select count(c.id) 
                        from comments c 
                        where c.post = posts.id AND c.user NOT IN (
                            select users.id from users where users.status = 3 OR users.status = 4
                        )
                    ) as numcomments,
                    ifnull(ru.rating, 0)  as myrating


                    FROM `relations`
                    JOIN `posts` ON relations.friend = posts.user
                    JOIN `users` ON relations.friend = users.id
                    LEFT JOIN `groups_posts` ON posts.id = groups_posts.post
                    LEFT JOIN ratings r ON r.post = posts.id 
                    LEFT JOIN ratings ru ON ru.post = posts.id and ru.user = 24527
                    WHERE relations.user = '24527' 
                        AND groups_posts.group is NULL
                        AND posts.status != 1 AND posts.status != 5
                        AND posts.date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
                        GROUP BY posts.id
                    UNION

                    SELECT posts.id, posts.text, posts.image, posts.date, posts.status, posts.location as postLocation, posts.user AS user, users.name, users.username, users.photo, users.location, users.bio, users.background, null as groupId, null as groupName, sum(r.rating) as rating
                    ,(
                        select count(re.id ) 
                        FROM relations re
                        WHERE re.user = users.id
                    ) as numfollowing,
                    (
                        select count(re.id ) 
                        FROM relations re
                        WHERE re.friend = users.id
                    ) as numfollowers,
                    (
                        select count(re.id)
                        FROM relations re
                        where re.friend = users.id
                        AND re.user = 24527
                    ) as following,
                    (
                        select count(c.id) 
                        from comments c 
                        where c.post = posts.id AND c.user NOT IN (
                            select users.id from users where users.status = 3 OR users.status = 4
                        )
                    ) as numcomments,
                    ifnull(ru.rating, 0)  as myrating
                    FROM `posts`
                    JOIN `users` ON posts.user = users.id
                    LEFT JOIN `groups_posts` ON posts.id = groups_posts.post
                    LEFT JOIN ratings r ON r.post = posts.id 
                    LEFT JOIN ratings ru ON ru.post = posts.id and ru.user = 24527
                    WHERE posts.user = '24527'
                        AND groups_posts.group IS NULL
                        AND posts.status != 1 AND posts.status != 5
                        AND posts.date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
                        GROUP BY posts.id
                    UNION

                    SELECT posts.id, posts.text, posts.image, posts.date, posts.status, posts.location as postLocation, posts.user AS user, users.name, users.username, users.photo, users.location, users.bio, users.background, groups.id as groupId, groups.name as groupName, sum(r.rating) as rating
                    ,(
                        select count(re.id ) 
                        FROM relations re
                        WHERE re.user = users.id
                    ) as numfollowing,
                    (
                        select count(re.id ) 
                        FROM relations re
                        WHERE re.friend = users.id
                    ) as numfollowers,
                    (
                        select count(re.id)
                        FROM relations re
                        where re.friend = users.id
                        AND re.user = 24527
                    ) as following,
                    (
                        select count(c.id) 
                        from comments c 
                        where c.post = posts.id AND c.user NOT IN (
                            select users.id from users where users.status = 3 OR users.status = 4
                        )
                    ) as numcomments,
                    ifnull(ru.rating, 0)  as myrating
                    FROM groups_members 
                    JOIN groups ON groups_members.group = groups.id
                    JOIN groups_posts ON groups_members.group = groups_posts.group
                    JOIN posts ON groups_posts.post = posts.id
                    JOIN users ON posts.user = users.id
                    LEFT JOIN ratings ru ON ru.post = posts.id and ru.user = 24527
                    LEFT JOIN ratings r ON r.post = posts.id 
                    WHERE groups_members.member = '24527'
                        AND groups_members.subscription = '1'
                        AND groups.status = '1'
                        AND posts.status != 1 AND posts.status != 5
                        AND posts.date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
                    GROUP BY posts.id
                    UNION 



   -- I need to add the SELECT below

                    SELECT companies_posts.id as `posts.id`, 
                    companies_posts.text as `posts.text`, 
                    companies_posts.image as `posts.image`,
                    companies_posts.date as `posts.date`, 
                    companies_posts.status as `posts.status`, 
                    null as postLocation,
                     companies_posts.company AS user, 
                    companies.name as `users.name`, 
                    companies.username as `users.username`, 
                    companies.photo as `users.photo`, 
                    null as `users.location`, 
                    companies.description as `users.bio`, 
                    companies.cover as `users.cover`, 
                    null as groupId, 
                    null as groupName, 
                    null as rating,
                    null as numfolllowing,
                    null as numfollowers,
                    null as following,
                    null as myrating,
                    null as numcomments



                    FROM `companies_subscriptions`
                    JOIN `companies_posts` ON companies_subscriptions.user = user
                    JOIN `companies` ON companies_subscriptions.company = companies.id
                    WHERE companies_subscriptions.user = '24527' 
                        AND companies_posts.status != 1 AND companies_posts.status != 5
                        AND companies_posts.date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
                        GROUP BY companies_posts.id
                        ORDER BY posts.date DESC, groupId DESC



                ) as posts

                LEFT JOIN users_blocked ON (users_blocked.user = posts.user AND users_blocked.blocked_friend = 24527) OR (users_blocked.user = 24527 AND users_blocked.blocked_friend = posts.user)
                WHERE 
                    users_blocked.user IS  NULL
                AND users_blocked.blocked_friend IS  NULL
                GROUP BY posts.id
                ORDER BY posts.date DESC

                LIMIT 0, 10
```

After fix a lot of errors, it is fetching... but returns me an error 1054 while fetch, as described on image below:

[image]
What's happening?

Comment: Google says 1504 means "Out of logbuffer memory", so I'm guessing it runs out of memory.

Comment: My apologies. Apparently I can't read. 1054 is "Unknown column in [something]"

Comment: But why after the fetching? Usually it happens BEFORE fetching. Actually happened a few times before now, and I was able to fix them.